# Why do comparisons in java 8 still use int instead of Enum?

Tags: java, enums, comparator

When using for example a comparator, the output of the `compare` method is an int. To me it seems that using an `Enum` (e.g. `Comparison`) with values like `Smaller`, `Equal` and `Larger` could make the code more readable and less error-prone.

```
// The comparison result could support methods
return compare(o1, o2).ifEqual(compare(o3, o4))

// Tests can be more readable
if(compare(o1, o2) == Equal && compare(o3, o4).isNot(Larger)) ...

// The compiler can now spot mistakes like returning a meaningless number
```

You could still support old style `compare(o1, o2).toInt() <= 1` and `Comparison.from(i2 - i1)`.

Is there any reason except that backwards compatibility would be tough to solve?

Comment: Aside from the other reasons, backward compatibility for something like this is pretty damn huge.

Comment: Because you cannot possibly change basic things like this. Even asking the question is pointless.

Comment: I do not agree that asking the question is pointless, otherwise you would never introduce disruptive APIs like NIO, new date API etc. You could very well introduce a new comparison API with converters or wrappers for the existing one. Howver I would maybe go for `if(compare(o1, GREATER, o2))` instead.

Comment: @EJP While I do not agree that anything must be cast in stone forever, I am also just interested in comparing the two representations and weigh the benefits and drawbacks independently of their current implementation cost. There might be other reasons why ints are a better candidate that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the return type from `int` to `Enum` will break all existing Comparators.
There's no real advantage of using an `Enum` instead of an `int` there, although it might make your code readable, if you're to return Enum values you have to do it yourself like below

```
if(o1 > o2){
  return ComparisonResult.GREATER;
}else if(o1 < o2){
  return ComparisonResult.SMALLER;
}else{
  return ComparisonResult.EQUAL;
}
```

or the JDK team has to change all the implementations of `compareTo` in many JDK classes like String, Integer etc., which is a lot of unnecessary work just because we want it to be more readable :)

Comment: Okay, I understand that at the current stage the benefits might not outweigh the cost, but are there inherent benefits of the int representation?

Comment: @Samuel in case of positive numbers result cold be written as simply as `return val1 - val2`.

Comment: I cannot list out the benefits of using an `int` but I would say it's merely a convention used in Mathematics and even in early low level programming languages like Assembly. For example if you look at `CMP eax,ebx` instruction, all they do is eax-ebx and set a flag if the result is -ve, +ve or 0, In the beginning of Java, we don't have any `Enum` type in Java, so to compare two things, one would ideally subtract one from another, applying the same analogy, they might have decided to use an `int` because it naturally represents the result of the comparison

Answer (score 2):

As you and others already pointed out, the main reason is likely backwards compatibility.

To increase readability and to avoid test code like `compare(o1, o2) < 0`, I wrote some utility methods some years ago. They're not using enums and don't address all the shortcomings you mentioned, but maybe you find them useful anyway (the library is Open Source):

http://www.softsmithy.org/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Comparables.html

Eg. given a Participant class like:

```
public class Participant {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String city;

    public Participant(String firstName, String lastName, String city) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
```

You could then write a comparator like this:

```
public class ParticipantComparator implements Comparator<Participant> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Participant o1, Participant o2) {
        if (Comparables.isEqual(o1.getFirstName(), o2.getFirstName())) {
            if (Comparables.isEqual(o1.getLastName(), o2.getLastName())) {
                if (Comparables.isEqual(o1.getCity(), o2.getCity())) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (Comparables.isGreater(o1.getCity(), o2.getCity())) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                if (Comparables.isGreater(o1.getLastName(), o2.getLastName())) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Comparables.isGreater(o1.getFirstName(), o2.getFirstName())) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you like, you could also use constants for the return values and static imports for the utility methods. Then the code would look like this:

```
import static org.softsmithy.lib.util.Comparables.isEqual;
import static org.softsmithy.lib.util.Comparables.isGreater;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class ParticipantComparator implements Comparator<Participant> {
    private static final int EQUAL = 0;
    private static final int GREATER = 1;
    private static final int LESS = -1;
    @Override
    public int compare(Participant o1, Participant o2) {
        if (isEqual(o1.getFirstName(), o2.getFirstName())) {
            if (isEqual(o1.getLastName(), o2.getLastName())) {
                if (isEqual(o1.getCity(), o2.getCity())) {
                    return EQUAL;
                } else if (isGreater(o1.getCity(), o2.getCity())) {
                    return GREATER;
                } else {
                    return LESS;
                }
            } else {
                if (isGreater(o1.getLastName(), o2.getLastName())) {
                    return GREATER;
                } else {
                    return LESS;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (isGreater(o1.getFirstName(), o2.getFirstName())) {
                return GREATER;
            } else {
                return LESS;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can download the library directly from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think this is more readable than the enum idea. How about some example usage in the answer?